# Edit single posts in a channel via admin panel

Tags: members, channel-preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit Channel Entry to 1?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/limit-channel-entry-to-1)

I have a site where one section of the site is a list of Useful links. Rather than have the client create a new channel post that will only include Website name & URL as the two channel fields, I set up a matrix that they can add to so, that they can move entries up or down.

I have explained to them the set up, that they must go in and edit this entry rather than add new channel entries for this, but just to be safe I want to lock this channel so they can't post new entries, just edit an existing. The member group preferences only allow **edit & post**, not **edit only** so just wondering has anyone done something similar.

Or should I just change my set up to channel entries for each useful link and create a low reorder set to move them round.

Comment: what about if selecting "Yes" to "Can edit entries authored by others"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of "locking" the channel to prevent users publishing additional entries, removing the entry from the Publish menu is often enough to do the trick. There are two add-ons that can help with this: [Single Entry](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/single-entry) or [CP Menu Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-menu-master) (formerly "Hidden Channels").

There are some other nice approaches listed in this possible duplicate question:
[Limit Channel Entry to 1?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/limit-channel-entry-to-1)

Comment: Some great answers there guys. Thanks for taking the time to respond. Will investigate these & post back the option that I used & how it worked out.

Comment: [Single Entry](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/single-entry) is what I ended up using. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you switched to using Structure, you can set up an Assets channel to list existing entries under the Assets tab instead of listing channels with Add/Edit links. Then you can direct the client to edit the entry under the Assets tab.